# Absent pageviews in google analytics view (but events are shown)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Besides standard view 'All data' I've created a separate view to track users by USER_ID from my database, following official documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en).

If I watch `User report` from 'All data' view, I can see both pageviews and events of users, but user ids aren't interpretable.

If I watch 'User report' from newly created USER_ID view, I can see events, but not page views! (I double checked that in filter above pageviews IS checked). How can I see both events AND pageviews?

My tacking code is

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=ID_OF_MY_RESOURCE"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '<ID_OF_MY_RESOURCE>');
  gtag('set', {'user_id': 'MY_USER_ID'});

</script>
```

and I send events with `gtag('event', 'event name', {'event_category' : 'some category', 'event_label' : 'some label'});` inside my web pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the `config` command sends the page view along with the base configuration. If you set the user_id value AFTER the `config` command, the page view hit doesn't know about it, but subsequent hits will use it.
And UserID views only collect hits that hold a value for the `user_id` parameter. This is why you don't get page views in it.

Then you just need to change line orders:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('set', {'user_id': 'MY_USER_ID'});
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '<ID_OF_MY_RESOURCE>');
</script>
```

There is no persistent *tracker* in gtag.js, just persistent *settings* that must be declared before sending a hit.